# What is the sentence constituent of "of gambling" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> I've cured people of gambling before.

I -- subject of the sentence;

have cured -- the predicate;

people  -- the object;

What about "of gambling"?

Comment: It is a prepositional object.

Answer (score 1):

It is the object of the preposition. "cure" does not accept multiple objects, it can only accept either the person being cured or the disease being cured. If you want to clarify what you are curing, you use a prepositional phrase to modify the verb, which makes "gambling" the object of that preposition "of" instead.

Comment: The object/complement of a preposition is no sentence part. It is only description of a word group.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider "of gambling" a second object. You can cure someone of something. By the way, I'm wondering how in English grammar terminology such objects preceded by a preposition are called (my term is prep-object). Unforunately it is usual in English grammar terminology to say the noun after a preposition is its object. In my view a terminology that only leads to confusion. The term object should only be used in connection with verbs.